# Ajax or Javascript not working on Wizard second step

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5

I have created a simple wizard in my MVC 5 project. The wizard consists of two steps which are rendered as partial view and a main View on which the two partial view are rendered. The code for my main View (Register.cshtml) is below,

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Register";
}

<div class="warper container-fluid">

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div id="divContainer">
                @Html.Partial("_RegisterBasic")
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The 1st PartialView is _RegisterBasic and its code is given below,

```
@model MyProject.Models.PersonalDetail

@{
    AjaxOptions options = new AjaxOptions();
    options.HttpMethod = "POST";
    options.InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace;
    options.UpdateTargetId = "divContainer";
}

<div class="panel-heading">Registration Form - Step 1 (BasicDetail)</div>
<div class="panel-body">
    <div class="col-md-12">
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("RegisterBasic", "Account", options, new { @class = "validator-form form-horizontal", role = "form", id = "RegisterBasicForm" }))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ContactName, new { @class = "col-sm-3" })
            <div class="col-md-9">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ContactName, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Contact Name (Optional)" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Address1, new { @class = "col-sm-3" })
            <div class="col-md-9">
                @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Address1, new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Address2, new { @class = "col-sm-3" })
            <div class="col-md-9">
                @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Address2, new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Town, new { @class = "col-sm-3" })
            <div class="col-md-9">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Town, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Town name (Optional)" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <button name="btnNext" type="submit" class="btn btn-success pull-right">Next</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

The second PartialView is _RegisterAccount and its code is,

```
@model eFormation_MVC.Models.RegisterUser

@{
    AjaxOptions options = new AjaxOptions();
    options.HttpMethod = "POST";
    options.InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace;
    options.UpdateTargetId = "divContainer";
}

<div class="panel-heading">Registration Form - Step 2 (Account Detail)</div>
<div class="panel-body">
    <div class="col-md-12">
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("RegisterAccount", "Account", options, new { @class = "validator-form form-horizontal", role = "form", id = "RegisterAccountForm" }))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()


        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "col-sm-3" })
            <div class="col-md-9">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Valid Email" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "col-sm-3" })
            <div class="col-md-9">
                @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Password" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword, new { @class = "col-sm-3" })
            <div class="col-md-9">
                @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Re-Type your Password" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <button id="btnRegisterUser" name="btnNext" type="submit" class="btn btn-success pull-right">Register</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

The respective Action methods are,

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Register()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult RegisterBasic(PersonalDetail data, string btnNext)
    {
        if (btnNext != null)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                Session["Personal"] = data;
                return PartialView("_RegisterUser");
            }
        }

        return PartialView("_RegisterBasic", data);
    }

    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult RegisterUser(RegisterUser data, string btnPrev, string btnNext)
    {
        if (btnNext != null)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                Session["User"] = data;
                return PartialView("_RegisterUser");
            }
        }
        else if (btnPrev != null)
        {
            return PartialView("_RegisterBasic", (PersonalDetail)Session["Personal"]);
        }

        return PartialView("_RegisterUser", data);
    }
```

Now the Ajax is working fine on Step 1. Client side validation is also working on Step 1. When I click "Next" button on Step 1 by entering basic details it shows me the second Step absolutely fine. But on Step 2 (Account Detail) the validation stopped working. Also when I click the "Submit" button on Step 2 then the call is not Ajax and the page is postback. Now it seems like Javascript has either stopped working on atleast unobtrusive part of JQuery has stopped working because neither validation is working on Step 2 which is done by jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js and nor Ajax is working which is done by jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js.

In the console their are no errors. The order in which the scripts files are called on the page is,

```
<script src="/Scripts/modernizr-2.8.3.js"></script>

<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

<script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.4.js"></script>

<script src="/Scripts/jquery.blockUI.js"></script>

<!-- jQuery Backstretch Plugin -->
<script src="/js/jquery.backstretch.min.js"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap -->
<script src="/assets/js/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Chosen -->
<script src="/assets/js/plugins/bootstrap-chosen/chosen.jquery.js"></script>

<!-- moment -->
<script src="/assets/js/moment/moment.js"></script>

<!-- NanoScroll -->
<script src="/assets/js/plugins/nicescroll/jquery.nicescroll.min.js"></script>

<!-- DateTime Picker -->
<script src="/assets/js/plugins/bootstrap-datetimepicker/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js"></script>


<!-- Bootstrap Validator -->
<script src="/assets/js/plugins/bootstrap-validator/bootstrapValidator.min.js"></script>


<script src="/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
```

Kindly check the code and help me in identifying the problem. Thanks

Comment: @AmmarCSE simple text, not scary.

Comment: Im taking a wild guess here. in the first form you use `options.InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace;`. When the second form is returned and replaced, Im *guessing* none of the validation handlers are binding because they are not delegated? Also, whatever is supposed to convert `Ajax.BeginForm` to actual ajax is not doing it for the same reason. Let me know if you want me to explain more

Answer (score 1):

Well. I have solved my issue somehow. Previously I had some problem with the file jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js as it was using an obsolete function "live" and it needed to be replaced with "on" to work. This solved the error. But when I checked everywhere for the problem I was not able to find any clue that why Ajax has stopped working. Just to make sure that everything is up to date, I one by one updated all Nuget packages. The problem persisted but when I updated jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js package then the problem got resolved and everything start working fine (both validation and Ajax). So I am posting this answer so may be this could be helpful.

Comment: Sorry again, I hope I didnt anger you . Forgive me :)

Comment: @AmmarCSE Not a problem. Cheers